# Rethrowing exception just as an information

Tags: java, exception-handling, exception

I have something like that:

1. My custom exception class:

   ```
   public class SolvableException extends RuntimeException {

       protected boolean solved = false;

       public SolvableException(String message) {
           super(message);
       }

       public void setSolved() {
           this.solved = true;
       }

       public boolean isSolved() {
           return this.solved;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Class for some very specific calculations which in some unpredictable cases throws my exception:

   ```
   class VerySpecificCalculator {
       public void makeSomeSpecificCalculations(double someParameter){
           // make some actions...
           // Now I have to make some specific calculations, but sth wrong happend and I do know what to do with it in this place...
           throw new SolvableException("Something wrong happend... Problem with XYZ");
       }
   }
   ```
3. My very specific calculator is used in other class and provides some part of its logic:

   ```
   class Calculator {
       public void makeSomeCalculations(double someParameter){
           // Some variuos calculations...
           VerySpecificCalculator calc = new VerySpecificCalculator();
           try {
               calc.makeSomeSpecificCalculations(4.34);
           } catch (SolvableException e){
               // I know what to do here, so I'm fixing a bug on this level:
               // some fixing code, some rollback whatever...
               e.setSolved();
               // But I want to inform, that the fixing process took place...
               throw e;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. I use the entire stuff as follows:

   ```
   class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
           try {
               calculator.makeSomeCalculations(344.47);
           }catch (SolvableException e){
               if(e.solved){
                   System.out.println("Ok, there was a problem but it has been solved... You can display some JOptionPane to inform a user if you want...");
               } else {
                   System.out.println("Buuu, there was a problem an it's still not solved... Action is interrupted ");
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Is this approach reasonable? I mean, is it ok to rethrow an exception if the problem has been already solved, and rethrowing plays only some informative role like in my example?

Let's consider such a situation (without rethrowing):

```
public void f(){
        try {
            methodCausingException();
        } catch (SolvableException e) {
            // fixing code...
        }
        //
        // Code executed when problem is fixed...
        //
    }
```

But with rethrowing I need to duplicate my code:

```
public void f(){
        try {
            methodCausingException();
        } catch (SolvableException e) {
            // fixing code...
            e.setSolved();
            //
            // Code executed when problem is fixed...
            //
            throw e;
        }
        //
        // Code executed when problem is fixed...
        //
    }
```

I can use a `finally` block, but I don't find this place as good for business logic code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Especially if you expect these exceptions to occur (relatively) often, I think that using exceptions is a bad idea here. [Exceptions should not be used for regular flow of control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control), this applies to Java as well. Creating and throwing exceptions is among the most costly operations there is in many programming languages.

One comment especially that caught my attention was: "Now I have to make some specific calculations, but sth wrong happend **and I do know what to do with it** in this place..." If you know what to do with it, then why are you throwing an exception? If you look in the [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exception) an exception is:

> special case, departure, *freak,* **anomaly,** inconsistency, deviation, quirk, **oddity,** peculiarity, **irregularity**" (+ exclusion, omission, objection).

Is your case really an *anomaly*? (Doesn't sound like it but I can't make this decision for you)

**Instead, consider** creating a `CalculationResult` class, which can be returned from your methods. The class can contain your `solved` variable (possibly among other things). Then when a method has returned a `CalculationResult` to it's caller, you can read the `CalculationResult` and decide what to do with it.

Comment: Being more specific: The problem causing an exception is solved deep in the model... Simply if some values are to high, they are reduced apropriately. But I want to inform about the fact of reducing some values in the view layer. That's why I'm rethrowing an exception with flag "solved". I know that it is probably not a perfect solution... I need simply something like that in this case... I do not want to show message dialogs in model layer (I'm working with swing). I consider your solution as well, thanks.

Comment: @guitar_freak Then it sounds like you should pass the `CalculationResult` to the view. Rethrowing exceptions itself is OK, but I don't think you should use exceptions here. If some values are too high, then modify them without throwing an exception - just change some information in the `CalculationResult`.

Comment: Other than that, you can alternatively Log a Warning, in case you have some logging mechanism in place ;)