# Null checking in nested getter calls

Tags: java, android, null

I have the following piece of code and I would like to see what different approaches would be to solve that in a more elegant way.

The thing is that I don't know whether is better to have the null checks or the try/catch block there or maybe the code below should not happen in the first place.  Maybe one can give another solution so that I can get the thumb URL from a images list that is set on a people object without having to check for null on each getter call.

```
if (people.getImages() != null && people.getImages().size() > 0 && people.getImages().get(0).getUrl() != null) {
    Url thumbUrl = people.getImages().get(0).getUrl().getThumb();
    // do something with the thumbUrl
}
```

Or I can have:

```
try {
    Url thumbUrl = people.getImages().get(0).getUrl().getThumb();
    // do something with the thumbUrl
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle the null pointer exception
}
```

**EDIT**

For more information, I am interested more in knowing if there any other ways to avoid calling getter methods one after another until I get my desired data from an object and if the above code is good enough anyway.

The code works ok in both cases but I don't like to have the multiple null checks in that if statement and also catching exceptions is not a good solution either.

The `getImages()` method returns a list of `Image` objects and `getThumb()` returns an `Url` object that I need in order to fetch an image over the internet.

Comment: An avoided exception is always better then a handled exception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about best practices, and isn't asking for code to be reviewed.

Comment: This question appears to be very borderline as there are not much code here, there is however something that can be said about the code that is seen here.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think that the question can be taken as a code review, I added two versions of code there and the problem is that I don't know which one is better or if there is another option.. if I am wrong, please guide me to a proper stack forum. Thanks

Comment: you haven't written the code yet @Cata, that is the problem.  do you know that your code works?  what is the context of the code? what is `people.getImages`? what is `getThumb`? we can't review this code, there isn't enough information.

Comment: @Malachi I have edited my question, gave you more information on the problem I have. Since Simon gave me a great answer and to the point I think that the question is somehow clear for some of the people here.. also I am happy to clarify my question in order to get answers and that is what I did so please review it again :). Thanks!

Comment: "or maybe the code below shouldn't happen in the first place." - probably yes, but we can't say  concerning that, as you have given only that code, isolated from the context. This makes an actual review of the code at hand in the full context (useful / sane or not) impossible. Your edit does not actually make the purpose of the code any clearer. Voting to leave closed. More info in [this meta-post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1937/37660) esp: "The excerpt is hypothetical in nature"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's count the number of times you're writing `get`.

```
if (people.getImages() != null && people.getImages().size() > 0 && people.getImages().get(0).getUrl() != null) {
    Url thumbUrl = people.getImages().get(0).getUrl().getThumb();
    // do something with the thumbUrl
}
```

5 times inside the if-condition and 4 times inside the block. That's a bit too much. Remember the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

In your case I would do:

```
if (people.hasImage(0)) {
     Url thumbUrl = people.getImage(0);
}
```

The idea is to hide some logic inside the `people` object.

It also seems like `people.getImages()` is a Collection, which makes me think that it is a bad idea to ever let that be null. An empty collection is better than a `null` collection.

As for your main question, I believe Heslacher says it all:

**An avoided exception is always better then a handled exception**

This applies *especially* to `NullPointerException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (and all other `RuntimeException`s).

Also, you should *always catch the most-specific Exception possible*. Never catch `Exception`. But then again, never catch `NullPointerException`. Fix your code to not cause one in the first place.

**Related previous Code Review answers about exceptions:**

[Rethrowing exception just as an information](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36125/rethrowing-exception-just-as-an-information/36128#36128)

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45637/exception-handling-with-instanceof-rather-than-catch/45639#45639